# git --ignore-blank-lines does not work. Is there any workaround?

Tags: git, diff

I do not want `diff` to show changes in empty lines (if they were added or removed), but

```
$ git diff --ignore-blank-lines
diff --git a/bin/requestHandlers.js b/bin/requestHandlers.js
index 758d02c..6d8b98d 100644
--- a/bin/requestHandlers.js
+++ b/bin/requestHandlers.js
@@ -1,3 +1,6 @@
+var exec = require("child_process").exec;
+
+
 function start() {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
```

it shows added empty lines at all.
Is there a way to force git to not show lines 2 and 3 in examle above?

Comment: what version of git are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an edit in the context, the option is ignored. Use a smaller context with [`-U`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--Ultngt). In your case `-U0`.

Example using git version 2.19.1.windows.1:

`git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines 539e08 7d05ca`

```
@@ -342,11 +385,14 @@ else
       )
       .Columns(columns =>
       {
-               columns.Bound(t => t.sStartDate).Title("Date".TranslateString(ref translation));
+          columns.Bound(t => t.StartDate).Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}").Title("Date".TranslateString(ref translation));
           columns.Bound(p => p.StartTime).ClientTemplate("#= sStartTime #").Title("StartTime".TranslateString(ref translation)).Width(110);
           columns.Bound(t => t.TrainingSubject).Title("Subject".TranslateString(ref translation));
+
       })
       .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
+
+
  .Sortable(s => s.Enabled(false)))

 <div style="clear:both;height:250px">&nbsp;</div>
(END)
```

`git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines -U0 539e08 7d05ca`

```
@@ -345 +388 @@ else
-               columns.Bound(t => t.sStartDate).Title("Date".TranslateString(ref translation));
+          columns.Bound(t => t.StartDate).Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}").Title("Date".TranslateString(ref translation));
```

Sometimes it's broken, though:

`git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines -U0 7d05ca`

```
@@ -394,3 +350 @@ else
-
-
- .Sortable(s => s.Enabled(false)))
+       .Sortable(s => s.Enabled(wut)))
```

Comment: This option affects context around changed lines and not the changed lines itself.

Comment: @EugenKonkov If git acts differently with + than - lines, perhaps this question is not a duplicate of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060463/git-option-to-ignore-empty-line-removal?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I blame Linus's rush. Though considering the state of Hurd and Minix, it's forgivable.

Comment: Thank for hint of `-U0` option. I count this is bug of git despite on `-U`: The lines in example are blank, so should be ignored

Answer (score 1):

From git's man page:

```
   --ignore-blank-lines
       Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.
```

The problem is that your change includes some lines which are not blank.

Remove the `var exec` line and it will work!

I don't know any way to do what you want though.  At least not neatly.

You could try:

```
git diff --ignore-blank-lines | grep -v '^\+$'
```